# Steel road bike with frame that hides cables

Tags: road-bike, steel, touring-bikes

I'm trying to recall the name of a bike maker that I had found while researching steel bikes a few months ago.  Their bike had a frame that hid cables.  i.e., the frame had holes to run the cables inside.  If my memory serves, they are based in Portland or somewhere else in Oregon and their bikes came only in red.

I had really liked this bike, but now I can't recall their name.  Does this ring a bell to anybody?

Comment: Internal cable routing has been around for decades on road bikes. That doesn't really narrow anything down.

Comment: @Batman: Has internal routing been a thing for STEEL framed bikes? I feel like I haven't come across it in my (admittedly limited road bike frame) experience. I'd be interested to know too.

Comment: I have an Italian 'Chesini' steel frame that has the rear brake cable running through the top tube. The frame is from the late 1980s.

Comment: @renesis - Yes, I've seen steel frames with internal cable routing since at least the 80s (and own an old steel frame with internal cable routing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if you were looking at the macho man disc, which has a steel frame and only comes in white/red:

http://allcitycycles.com/bikes/macho_man_disc

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  You won't believe how much relieved I am to learn that the company still exists and I found the name :)

Comment: Yes they're alive and well, and the bikes have been getting better and better too.

Answer (score 1):

My google-fu suggests these as possibilities.

- http://ticycles.com/    Titanium not steel, and not red. In Portland, and handmade.
- http://www.cylo.cc/    Red and in Portland, but not steel.  Looks like a "coming soon" rather than an actual product.
- http://breadwinnercycles.com/   Rolls up Ira Ryan cycles, http://www.iraryancycles.com/ and hand makes frames.

Do let us know when you find them.